# In Python, how do I write a loop to remove from character # n to a specific character (:) in parts of a list that match a condition?

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list like this:

```
test = ["Similar to Stxbp2: Syntaxin-binding protein 2 (Mus musculus)", "Protein of unknown function", "Similar to rab18b: Ras-related protein Rab-18-B (Danio rerio)", "Protein of unknown function", "Protein of unknown function"]
```

This object is, in actuality, a lot longer than this, but just for a simplified example:
My goal is to loop through `test` and edit it to where any value starting with "Similar to" will return the gene name proceeding directly after (e.g., for this example I'd like to replace the items in the list matching this beginning with "Stxb2" and "rab18b", respectively), which I presume would require specifying to start at character 12 and end when it reaches a colon. When a value includes "Protein of unknown function", I want it to return "Unknown". Thus, the output would be:

```
["Stxbp2", "Unknown", "rab18b", "Unknown", "Unknown"]
```

I know this probably requires a for loop with if statements to match each condition, but am pretty lost in how to proceed from there to achieve the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Are there only two possibilities for the strings - i.e., it will either start with `"Protein of unknown function"` or `"Similar to"`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Yes!

Comment: You should include the exact output you expect here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variation without regex if you don't like those:

```
def parse(x):
    if x.startswith("Similar to"):
        return x.split(":")[0].split()[-1]
    if x.startswith("Protein of unknown function"):
        return "Unknown"
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown value: {x}")

print([parse(i) for i in test ])
```

outputs:

```
['Stxbp2', 'Unknown', 'rab18b', 'Unknown', 'Unknown']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using list comprehension by matching your condition using `str.startswith` and then use `str.split` to split on the `:`

```
[x[11:].split(':', 1)[0] if x.startswith('Similar to') else 'Unknown' for x in test ]
# -> ['Stxbp2', 'Unknown', 'rab18b', 'Unknown', 'Unknown']
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a list comprehension along with a regex replacement:

```py
test = ["Similar to Stxbp2: Syntaxin-binding protein 2 (Mus musculus)", "Protein of unknown function", "Similar to rab18b: Ras-related protein Rab-18-B (Danio rerio)", "Protein of unknown function", "Protein of unknown function"]
d = {'Similar to ': '', 'Protein of unknown function': 'unknown'}
regex = r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b'
output = [re.sub(regex, lambda m: d[m.group()], x).split(':')[0] for x in test]
print(output)  # ['Stxbp2', 'unknown', 'rab18b', 'unknown', 'unknown']
```

The strategy here is the dictionary contains, as keys, the search terms, with the values as replacements.  We build a regex alternation of the keys, and then use `re.sub()` in callback mode.  For each matching key, we lookup the replacement.